# Having trouble accessing React actions in isomorphic application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript, alt.js

Iam using Alt.js with React and getting error in HomeActions.js file `HomeActions.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateUserSuccess' of undefined`. Not to mention the same code was working flawlessly before i completely reinstalled node_modules.

here is the code

```
import alt from '../../alt';
import request from 'superagent';

class HomeActions {
    constructor() {
        this.generateActions(
            'updateUserSuccess',            
        );
    }

    getUser() {
        request
            .get('api/getuser')
            .end((err, res) => {
                this.actions.updateUserSuccess(res.text);
            });
    }                       
}

export default alt.createActions(HomeActions);
```

`getUser()` is called in the `componenetdidmount(){}` function of Home.js

Also directly calling the action property from the component does work so i guess the problem is not with Alt.js or generateActions : eg

```
import alt from '../../alt';

class NavbarActions {
  constructor() {
    this.generateActions(
      'updateOnlineUsers'
    );
  }

}

export default alt.createActions(NavbarActions);

//in Navbar.js
componentDidMount() {
    NavbarStore.listen(this.onChange);
    NavbarActions.updateOnlineUsers(somedata);
  }

//this is working**
```

*This question might be related to my last question about calling a function inside an instance method.*

*Sidenote : After updating the dependencies I also had to make changes to use `RouterContext` istead of `RoutingContext` in the server-side react-middle-ware, and to solve an issue related to that I imported `browserHistory` from `react-router` (before i was using `createBroswerHistory` from `'history/createBrowserHistory'`)*

Edit 1 : I replaced `this.actions.updateUserSuccess(res.text);` with `alt.actions.HomeActions.updateUserSuccess(res.text);` and the `updateUserSuccess` is accessible but still getting a warning `ReferenceError: An action was called but nothing was dispatched`

Edit 2 : I just got to the core of the issue by using `console.log(this);` in the newer version and also in the older version here are the logs

Older version :

```
AltAction {id: "HomeActions.getTwoCharacters", actions: Object, actionDetails: Object, alt: Alt, dispatched: false}
_dispatch : ()
actionDetails :
Object actions :
Object alt :
Alt dispatched :
false id :
"HomeActions.getTwoCharacters"
__proto__ : Object
```

New Version

```
Object {GET_USER: "HomeActions.getUser", LOGOUT: "HomeActions.logout", UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS: "HomeActions.updateUserSuccess", UPDATE_USER_FAIL: "HomeActions.updateUserFail", LOGOUT_SUCCESS: "HomeActions.logoutSuccess"…}
GET_USER : "HomeActions.getUser"
LOGOUT : "HomeActions.logout"
LOGOUT_FAIL : "HomeActions.logoutFail"
LOGOUT_SUCCESS : "HomeActions.logoutSuccess"
UPDATE_USER_FAIL : "HomeActions.updateUserFail"
UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS : "HomeActions.updateUserSuccess"
getUser  :  action()
logout :  action()
logoutFail : action()
logoutSuccess : action()
updateUserFail : action()
updateUserSuccess : action()
__proto__ :  Object
```

Clearly there is no dispatching method in the newer version. Can somebody explain why is this so?